# Remove external link in excel 2010 from one worksheet

Tags: hyperlink, excel-2010

I've a workbook containing 17-18 worksheets.

I've an external link (vlookup formula) on some sheets.  I want to remove the external link on particular worksheet (say sheet1 & sheet5) only.  But, when i tried "break link" it remove the links from entire workbook.
pl. help. Thanks

Comment: searched web to get the solution, but, every solution claims to use "PASTE SPECIAL as VALUES" :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of removing the links. I am sure there should be other simple ways to do it. I found below process only for now!

Download Download Dellinks.exe now from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188449

Place these files in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\Library

1. Close all the windows in excel
2. Go to Add-Ins -> Wizard -> Delete links. It opens a new window
3. Select the file which you want to delete and click Next.
4. Select the operations you want to do.
5. Finish.